# How to find out what is using Exchange 2010 certificate (two certificates used by SMTP)

Tags: windows, ssl, exchange, exchange-2010, windows-server-2012-r2

I have installed out new wildcard via the GUI.

I have assigned IIS and SMTP to it.

When I view the old wildcard it still shows SMTP under services.

I can run Get-Certificate but all it gives me is SMTP, is there any way of finding out where in exchange this certificate is used, more detailed than just SMTP.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean you ran the `Get-ExchangeCertificate` command in the EMS.

You can get the same info from the EMC but you've gotten the information you need. The certificate is being used by SMTP. That's it.

Comment: How can SMTP be bound to multiple SSL certs? How do I know if I remove the old one it will not break.

Comment: It is possible for multiple certificates to be bound to SMTP. See here for how to remove it - http://serverfault.com/questions/699633/how-to-unassign-self-signed-cert-from-smtp-on-exchange-2010